# How do I emulate "play/pause" button keystroke in Applescript (Big Sur)

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, applescript

I am running Big Sur and using Apple USB keyboard with arrow keys and numpad, and have function keys F1, F2, F3,... F19

The key (F19) is located on the top right corner. I am interested in assigning this key as the media "play/pause" button that is already existing on F8 key.

I tried the following apple script:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 0.5
        
        key code 100
        
    end tell
end run
```

When I run the script, nothing happens.

I also tried `key code {63, 100}` and `key code {100, 63}` but that had no effect.
I made sure that Automator is added to Accessibility Security permissions. Also, the existing F8 key works perfectly when I press it from any application on the mac. It pays or pauses music or youtube video regardless if video or music is active or in the background.

How can I assign F19 key to do the play/pause ?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is - the play/pause key **isn't** F8.
It's the play/pause key.

If you go to System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard, you'll see the pref "Use F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys"
This toggles whether pressing the key marked F8 sends actual F8 or Play/Pause. You can swap the behaviour temporarily by holding the Fn key.

Regular F-Keys can be intercepted or sent as key commands just like any other key. As you found, F8 itself is key code 100.

Here's where it fails…
The play/pause key doesn't register to the keyboard interpreter in the same way. It is combined inside the keyboard & happens before any high-level interpreter has access to it. The OS at very low level sends that key to, for instance, iTunes [even to the extent that it will launch it, if it's not running] then play/pause.
You cannot intercept or replace this.

In effect, what you need is something that can get in underneath the interpreter.

There are a few apps that can achieve this - [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai), [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/) [for which I found some scripting at https://gist.github.com/NoobsArePeople2/5121597] and [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)
I don't have precise details of how you'd achieve it with these apps, but they all have good help & references.